# Calculate $\int\frac{\ln^2(a+bx)}{x^n}dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I know the solve the integral $$\int\frac{\ln(a+bx)}{x^n}dx$$ by the integration by parts method.
I'm interested to solve the given integral
$$\int\frac{\ln^2(a+bx)}{x^n}dx$$ **by the parts method**
Thanks for help.

Comment: It's amazing to me how much easier it is if you replace $ \ln(a+bx)$ with $\ln(x)$ in both of the above. WolframAlpha says the answer involves the hypergeometric function, which I know nothing about.